# How to add a date to a prisma typescript form?

Tags: prisma, typegraphql

I am trying to figure out how to post a date to a prisma database.

I have a prisma.schema which has a createdAt field as follows:

```
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
```

I made a model with a date field in it as follows:

```
@Field()
  createdAt: Date;
```

And a create.input.ts with a similar field:

```
@IsNotEmpty()
  @Field()
  createdAt: Date;
```

then, in the form, I'm trying to add the createdAt date as the date the form is submitted, as follows:

```
 return form.handler(() => createIssueGroup({ variables: { data: { ...data, createdAt: Date.now() } } })),
```

However, I get an error that says type number is not assignable to type string. I don't think I'm using a string in any of the date fields.

How can I post a date to prisma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your schema definition,

`createdAt       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)`

The date will be automatically generated due to the `now()` method you specified in `@default()`. You don't need to pass a date to the database as that will be handled for you by Prisma. See the docs for more information on [using now()](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#now) and [defining a default value](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-a-default-value).